# How to substitute missing font when filling a form with PDFBox?

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

I'm trying to fill out a bunch of PDF Forms using PDFBox 2.0.8. For some documents I get the following error when setting the PDTextField's value:

```
java.io.IOException: Could not find font: /ArialMT
```

Apparently the font is not correctly embedded as is often the case with proprietary Microsoft fonts.

How can I tell PDFBox to substitute the font e.g. with "normal" Arial or some other font? Setting the fields DA string to `"/Helv 0 tf 0 g"` resulted in a NullPointerException.

Comment: add the font with that name (e.g. Helv) to the acroform default resources. Beware: do not subset fonts. You can use the predefined type 1 font if you're sure that only WinAnsiEncoding if used. More explanation if you share the file. Please use 2.0.9 (and open an issue in JIRA if you get an NPE again with your "bad" solution).

Comment: `acroForm.getDefaultResources().put(COSName.getPDFName("Helv"), PDType1Font.HELVETICA);`

Comment: And how would I add e.g. Arial to the resources in a way that I can use it in  a DA string? `put(COSName.getPDFName("Arial"), <font from fs>)`?

Comment: You create the font with PDType0Font.load () use the 3 parameter method and third parameter must be false.

Comment: Thank you. The problematic document can be found at https://www.main-donau-netz.de/static-resources/content/resources/doc/F2_Datenblatt_022015.pdf

Comment: NPE is still there. Created https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4235

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments from Tilman Hausherr I built a first fix which works independent from the operating system (which is a Linux in my case).

```
acroForm.defaultResources.put(COSName.getPDFName("ArialMT"),
    PDType0Font.load (pdDocument, this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("fonts/ARIALMT.ttf"), false))
```

This will only work for this particular font, though. What's still missing - and was actually the main intention of my question - is an option to tell PDFBox to fall back to a certain font resp. DA if the font that is required cannot be provided.

After Tilman again came for the rescue I can now present the complete solution. Again, this is Kotlin, not Java:

```
PDDocument.load(file).use { pdDocument ->
    val acroForm = pdDocument.documentCatalog.acroForm
    acroForm.defaultResources.put(COSName.getPDFName("ArialMT"),
            PDType0Font.load (pdDocument, this.javaClass.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("fonts/ARIALMT.ttf"), false))
    val pdField: PDField? = acroForm.getField(fieldname)
    val value = ...
    when (pdField) {
        is PDCheckBox -> {
            if (value is Boolean) {
                when (value) {
                    true -> pdField.check()
                    false -> pdField.unCheck()
                }
            } else {
                log.error("RENDER_FORM: Need Boolean for ${pdField.fullyQualifiedName} but got $value")
            }
        }
        is PDTextField -> {
            try {
                pdField.value = value?.toString() ?: ""
            } catch (ioException: IOException) {
                pdField.cosObject.setString(COSName.DA, "/Helv 0 Tf 0 g")
                pdField.value = value?.toString() ?: ""
                log.error("RENDER_FORM: Writing text field failed: ${ioException.message}")
            }
        }
        null -> {
            log.error("RENDER_FORMULAR: Formfield $fieldname does not exist in $name")
        }
        else -> log.error("RENDER_FORMULAR: Formfield $pdField ($fieldname) is of unhandled type ${pdField.fieldType}")
    }

    val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    pdDocument.save(stream)
    pdDocument.close()
    return stream.toByteArray()
}
```

Comment: Waahahahhaaaa.... You have no idea how much time this typo cost me. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add "ArialMT" to the default resources:

```
try (PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(new File("F2_Datenblatt_022015.pdf")))
{
    PDAcroForm acroForm = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
    PDField field = acroForm.getField("Vorname_Name");

    // fails with IOException as described in question
    //field.setValue("Tilman Hausherr");

    // Method 1, just add type1 Helvetica (allows only WinAnsiEncoding glyphs)
    //acroForm.getDefaultResources().put(COSName.getPDFName("ArialMT"), PDType1Font.HELVETICA);

    // Method 2, add the full Arial font (allows for more different glyphs)
    // important: use the method that switches off subsetting
    acroForm.getDefaultResources().put(
        COSName.getPDFName("ArialMT"), 
        PDType0Font.load(doc, new FileInputStream("c:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf"), false));


    field.setValue("Tilman Hausherr");

    doc.save("F2_Datenblatt_022015-mod.pdf");
}
```

Update:
Turns out the code in the question would have worked too with the file - almost. It's "Tf" and not "tf", so the string would have been "/Helv 0 Tf 0 g". We'll research how to avoid an NPE and get a meaningful exception.

Comment: I did something similar but a bit more platform independent. See my answer for reference, please. :-)