# How do you substitute free fonts for some/all of the standard 14 fonts using PDFBox 2.0.27?

Tags: java, fonts, pdfbox

We're using PDFBox 2.0.27 to print PDF documents in Java on Linux. We'd like to use free fonts (like Linux Libertine for Times-Roman) for rendering the image. Is there a way to map the 14 standard fonts used by PDF to other fonts?

I've tried just installing the alternative fonts on my system, but I can't figure out how to map them to the standard font set or give them an alias.

Comment: [How to substitute missing font when filling a form with PDFBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609478/how-to-substitute-missing-font-when-filling-a-form-with-pdfbox)

Comment: PDFBox does it automatically, it knows commonly used fonts; see the log output to see whether there are problems. Install these: https://itsfoss.com/install-microsoft-fonts-ubuntu/